# C# How to Call static method from subclass

Tags: c#, class, static

I have this code:

```
class Super{ 
   public static List<Super> methodA() { . . . }
}
class Sub:Super{ 
   public static List<Sub> methodA() { . . . }
}
```

Then I call :

```
 Sub.methodA();
```

But the executed is from super class. Anyway I can exec the subclass's static method? They has **same static method name**.

Update:
[image]
You can see that Product is my superclass and purchase is subclass. Both has same static getAll() but returned different type. In this case it returns the List

Comment: Actually `Sub.methodA()` will execute the static method from the subclass

Comment: Tried it, but instead calling from Subclass's method, it called to the super class's.

Comment: @user2936719 Either your sample is irrelevant to your real code, or you're missing something. But really - `Sub.methodA()` in code you've shown will call sub method and never super one.

Comment: @user2936719, then you are doing something wrong as `Sub.methodA()` can only call `methodA` in `Sub`.

Comment: you're definitly doing something wrong. the call should execute `Sub.methodA()` not `Super.methodA()` if you wanna make sure you're creaing a new method with your implementation of `Sub` add a `new` keyword to your static method

Comment: When dealing with static methods, inheritance is irrelevant. Sub.methodA() will execute  methodA of class Sub.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of Product and Purchase (just the line that defines the class like `public class Purchase : ...`) in the question? It is strange to see a Purchase inheriting from a Product.

Comment: class Purchase : Product { . . . . }

Comment: From the images attched, you can see that is the Super class's static method, but it referenced to the subclass's methods which is Purchase.GetAll()

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I suggest Purchase should not be a subclass of Product.  It should hold a reference to Product.  i recommend you revise your ERD.

Comment: Maybe that is any issue of Code Map. Place some break points inside `Product.GetAll` and `Purchase.GetAll` and then see which will get called when you invoke `Purchase.GetAll`. It is definitely going to be `Purchase.GetAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same method name in a subclass as provided from the super class, you'd have to override it - however it is not possible for static methods in C#.

Please take a look at this article, it provides good insides into that topic:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-override-static-methods.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`methodA` in subclass will hide the method in the base class. So `Sub.methodA` will call the method in the **sub** class, not the base class.

> Sub.MethodA()' hides inherited member 'Super.MethodA()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Answer (score 0):

`Super.methodA();` will call the super's static method from anywhere... from the super class, from the sub class, from outside both classes, etc

`Sub.methodA();` will call the sub's static method from anywhere...

Here's my test code:

```
class Program
{
    class Super
    {
        public static List<Super> methodA() { Console.WriteLine("SUPER"); return new List<Super>(); }

        public void callSuper()
        {
            Super.methodA();
        }

        public void callSub()
        {
            Sub.methodA();
        }
    }
    class Sub : Super
    {
        public static List<Sub> methodA() { Console.WriteLine("SUB"); return new List<Sub>(); }

        public void callSuper()
        {
            Super.methodA();
        }

        public void callSub()
        {
            Sub.methodA();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Super.methodA();

        Sub.methodA();

        var s = new Sub();
        s.callSuper();
        s.callSub();

        var Sup = new Super();
        Sup.callSuper();
        Sup.callSub();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: From comparing your edits to your original question, I get the impression that something got lost when you put together your test example, and we are not getting the full picture of your issue.  I was shocked when my test code (above) compiled without errors or warnings... so that tells me that your issue has nothing to do with Super versus Sub.  If you are still having trouble, I recommend you rename your methods to GetAllProducts and GetAllPurchases.

Comment: If you were to rename these methods, even just temporarily, it might make it easier to find your issue.  From looking at your edits, I suspect maybe one of your declarations is incorrect, but I'm not sure because we don't have the full picture.

Comment: hey user2936719, select my answer...  I need the points !!   just kidding (or am I?).  What was the final result of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This works as intended see the below sample([runnable](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O7kABv)). Something got screwed up between your sample code and your real code.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Sub.methodA());
        Console.WriteLine(Super.methodA());
    }
}
class Super{ 
   public static List<Super> methodA() { return new List<Super>(); }
}
class Sub:Super{ 
   public new static List<Sub> methodA() { return new List<Sub>(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call them using type name :

```
 Sub.methodA();
 Super.methodA();
```

Static method exists only for class where it is declared. It can't be inherited and it cannot be called on instance of the class.

```
class Super
{
    public static char methodA() 
    {
        return 'a'; 
    }
}
class Sub : Super
{
    public static char methodA() 
    {
        return 'b'; 
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = Sub.methodA();
        var res2 = Super.methodA();

        Console.WriteLine(res == res2);

        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output: `false`

Answer (score 0):

This is called "hiding" and not "overriding".  While not recommended, it is indeed valid.  If you invoke Super.MethodA, it runs the method on the base class.  If you run Sub.MethodA, it runs the method in the derived class.  I just verified this to be 100% certain.

You might want to rethink your design here.  If the idea is just to allow someone to get a list of your objects without having to new up a class every time, there are a lot of different ways to do this that don't require hiding.  Some implementation details might be helpful in allowing us to suggest a valid approach.